# How to drop unnecessary levels after using pivot_table?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pivot-table

I would like to structure a pandas dataframe appropriately so that I can plot it as desired. As far as I can determine, the best way to structure the data is to use pivot table, but I'm having issues with what I guess I'll call "residual levels".

```
# Trying to determine why pivot table keeps level "Test 1" in data frame

import itertools as it
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate some data; covert dict to dataframe
MyDates = list(it.repeat(['1/1/19', '2/1/19', '3/1/19', '4/1/19', '5/1/19'],
                         5))
MyDates_flat = [item for sublist in MyDates for item in sublist]
MyDates_flat.sort()

SampleSites = ['Site 1', 'Site 2', 'Site 3', 'Site 4', 'Site 5'] * 5

Test1 = list(np.random.randint(0, 10, 25))
Test2 = list(np.random.randint(0, 10, 25))
Test3 = list(np.random.randint(0, 10, 25))

MyData = {'Date': MyDates_flat, 'Sample Location': SampleSites,
          'Test 1': Test1, 'Test 2': Test2, 'Test 3': Test3}
DF1 = pd.DataFrame(MyData)
```

Once pivot table is used, "Test 1" remains and prevents me from plotting columns for `Site 1`, `Site 2`, etc.

```
# Filter for columns that you want to eventually plot; use pivot_table to -
# restructure data for plotting.
DF2 = DF1.filter(['Date', 'Sample Location', 'Test 1'], axis=1)
DF_Test1 = DF2.pivot_table(index='Date',
                           columns='Sample Location')

# How to get rid of "Test 1" over Site columns?

# Plot each site as its own series (line)
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(12, 4))
plt.plot(DF_Test1.index, DF_Test1['Site 1'], color='red')
plt.plot(DF_Test1.index, DF_Test1['Site 2'], color='blue')
plt.plot(DF_Test1.index, DF_Test1['Site 3'], color='green')
# etc.
```

If I export the data frame `DF_Test1` as an excel file and remove the row with 'Test 1', I can plot the columns for Site 1, Site 2, etc.  How can I do this in python?  I've attempted using droplevel and drop without success.  Thank you.

Comment: `DF_Test1 = DF2.pivot_table(index='Date', columns='Sample Location', values='Test 1')`

Comment: I was confused because the documentation described "values" as the column to aggregate, I see now it doesn't have to be so.  Thank you.